# Joining data points to matching polygons

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, polygon, spatial-database

I have polygon data on coral reefs at great barrier reef and separate point data for areas of coral bleaching. I have created a clip that only includes points that exist with in the reef polygons. However I need to be able to identify polygons that have bleaching points in them from those that do not. So for example I would like to be able to click on a polygon that has a bleaching point in it and it automatically select all the other polygons that do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use a select by location (from the selection menu) to identify all polygons that contain your bleaching data points. then add a field (options/add field...) to the reef polygon attribute table, and calculate values for the selected features with the field calculator (right click on the field name, select 'field calculator')to assign a value to differentiate between bleached and unbleached reefs (Y/N or 1/0).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to select all polygons with a bleaching point in them, you can "select > [select by location](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000072000000)".

If you want to select all polgon with a given characterstic when you click on it, you need to use "[dissolve](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Dissolve/00170000005n000000/)" in order to have multipart poylgon. The first step would be a "[spatial join](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000000q000000)" in order to find out which polygons include a point .